# Highcharts basic line chart - Y-axis label name

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts Basic Line chart, Y-axis label how need to show ?

Here is my code

```
  var seriesData = [["O", 42], ["N", 35], ["D", 20], ["J", 47], ["F", 45], ["M", 65]];
            var seriesDataY = [['O', 50], ['14', 22], ["D", 30], ["J", 42], ["F", 44], ["M", 65]];

            Highcharts.chart('linechart', {
                title: {
                    text: ' '
                },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: '(6 mth period)'
                    },

                    labels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function () { return seriesDataY[0][this.value]; },
                    }

                },


                xAxis: {
                    tickInterval: 1,
                    labels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function () { return seriesData[this.value][0]; },
                    }
                },

                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle'
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        label: {
                            connectorAllowed: false
                        },
                        pointStart: 0
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Voluntary',
                    data: seriesData 
                }, {
                    name: 'Involuntary',
                    data: seriesDataY
                    //data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452]
                }],


                responsive: {
                    rules: [{
                        condition: {
                            maxWidth: 500
                        },
                        chartOptions: {
                            legend: {
                                layout: 'horizontal',
                                align: 'center',
                                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }

            });
```

Images attached:

[image]

Y-axis label is missing:

0, 14 , 28,42, 56,70

As per the above value, i need to show the Y-axis. What is the option to show the Y-axis label name?

Comment: Try return seriesDataY[this.value][0]; for Y-axis

Comment: Currently the yAxis.labels.formatter callback returns undefined in your case - that's why labels don't show up. Could you explain what would you like to render in place of basic yAxis values?

Comment: seriesDataY[this.value][0];chart not get loaded. Y-axis label name 0, 14 , 28,42, 56,70. Like X-axis need to show O,N,D,J,F,M

Answer (score 1):

Notice that yAxis takes values (this.value) from the data y numbers. That's why it is different than for xAxis. Also, notice that the amount of the labels for yAxis is calculated differently, so it has to be set.

I think that something like this should fit your requirements:

```
let i = 0;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: ' '
  },
...
  labels: {
   enabled: true,
   formatter: function() {

     i++;
     return seriesDataY[i - 1][0];
   },
 }
...
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zsou1Lye/

Comment: Not working if given  return seriesDataY[i - 1][0];

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the page? In my case, the chart hasn't rendered for the first time (I have no idea why), but after page reload works fine.

Comment: I found that the better solution will be with the condition checks if value exist: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1btdxu7/